# Evaluating the Sensitivity and Specificity of Various AI Detection Tools in Academic Settings

Tags: plagiarism, generative-ai

I'm researching the effectiveness of AI detection tools in identifying AI-generated text, especially in the context of academic integrity. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the sensitivity and specificity of the following tools:

1. Unicheck.com
2. Originality.ai
3. Contentatscale.ai
4. Gowinston.ai
5. Undetectable.ai

My primary question is whether any scientific studies or empirical data are available that evaluate these tools' accuracy in differentiating between human-written and AI-generated text. In this context, sensitivity would refer to the tool's ability to correctly identify AI-generated content, while specificity would relate to correctly recognizing human-generated content.

Given the increasing use of AI in generating academic texts, it's crucial to understand how reliable these tools are in maintaining academic integrity. I'm particularly interested in:

- Any peer-reviewed studies that have tested these tools.
- Data on false positive/negative rates.
- Comparative analyses of these tools against others in the market.
- Personal experiences or anecdotal evidence from the academic community regarding using these tools.

Comment: Note that [sensitivity and specificity suffer from all the same major problems as accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352). Better to work with probabilistic than hard 0-1 classifications, and if these really need to be compared to a threshold, then [select this threshold with a lot of care](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).